# How does a browser handle multiple cookies with the same name?

Tags: http, cookies, browser, header

I noticed a web site that is issuing two cookie headers with the same name, path, domain, and other attributes.  The headers appear one after the other in the HTTP response headers for the same round trip.  The only thing that differs is the value.

When I submitted my next request, only one cookie header was presented.

What is the expected browser behavior in this situation?  Will the browser always send the cookie that it received "last"?  Does that mean the second cookie will always win?  Or is the behavior undefined, and the browser will just pick one at random?

Without any other information, is it fair to say that the double cookie headers is a bug?  Or is there ever a situation where this would be desired behavior?